# Android Espresso: How to match text on custom spinner selected item layout?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-testing, android-espresso

I have spinner with custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**And I need to check if value in `R.id.tv_text` of selected item match with specific text. 
Is it possible to do this without implement custom Matcher class ?**

My simple test:

```
@SmallTest
public class CategoryTest {

    public static final String TEXT_TO_MATCH = "Spinner item text";

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        ...
        onView(withId(R.id.spn_tt)).perform(click()); // open spinner
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.tv_text), withText(TEXT_TO_MATCH))).perform(click()); // find item by text and click
        onView(withId(R.id.spn_tt)).check(matches(withTextInSpinnerSelectedView(TEXT_TO_MATCH))); // check if right item selected by text
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found more simple way than create custom matcher that looks for specific text in any TextView (or their heirs) of Spinner selected item. There is a my custom matcher: https://gist.github.com/igorokr/5f3db37f0b9eb8b2feae

Comment: so your problem is solved or you're looking for another solutions :-D

Comment: @piotrek1543 my problem was resolved but I will be thankful for more simple solution if exists.

Answer (score 3):

I have archieved that using a custom matcher too. But i have used a less verbose matcher, maybe it helps someone:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click());
 onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(YourCustomClass.class)), withMyValue("Open"))).perform(click());


public static <T> Matcher<T> withMyValue(final String name) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            return item.toString().equals(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    };
}
```

Then you must override toString() method on your custom class.

Comment: This is a good approach. One downside is I have to create one method for each case.

Answer (score 3):

Really simple solution that worked out for me .....without using matcher
for CustomSpinner

```
onView(withId(R.id.custom_spinner)).perform(click());
onData(anything()).atPosition(1).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.custom_spinner)).check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString("yourstring"))));
```